ZFS error for load-key
I've tried everything I know until I'm exhausted. Please, if you can help me, I need to access my project stored on my hard drive.
The command I used:
sudo zfs load-key rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uy913x

And the error message I received:
Key load error: Keys must be loaded for encryption root of 'rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uy913x' (rpool).


Because that's the enc key of the dataset itself.
Check key availability/correctness with:
zfs get -Ho property,value encryptionroot,keystatus rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uy913x

respectively:
zfs get -Ho property,value encryptionroot,keystatus rpool/ROOT

The keystatus has to be reported as "available".
In your case, the command:
zfs load-key -r rpool/ROOT

should be the correct one. That loads all datasets recursively.

HELLO
Thanks
This is the output
encryptionroot rpool
keystatus unavailable
I dont know why isnt go

Same here, any solution?
